# Set FTP file download limit in pentaho job

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a pentaho job which contain "get file with ftp" entry which download all file from remote server to local. How can i limit the file download to a specified number, ie:if 300 files are there in remote directory i want to download only 50 random files in each execution.

Comment: No direct property, you have to create some logic for this.

Comment: can you please suggest one logic for this.@WorkingHard..

Answer (score 0):

I did similar specific ftp requirements like yours from a **User Java class step** in the past.

Its the only way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the JOB steps for downloading FTP files work only with a RegExp, which will download all files one by one that match, OR, by passing a filename/URI one by one.

If you need a pause between the execution of a group of N files, then there is way to achieve it, you would use a Transformation Executor to segregate a group of N files, and then use a JOB Executor to pass each file of this group to the JOB step, you would then implement the pause you want before each group of 50 files.